# trouble using ajax to send form values to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send the form values to another php file. After confirming to send the data, I will not receive the alert notification from the php file.

What i tried doing: I tried creating a test file with the shortened down version of the code, surprisingly that works

This is the first file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include('../class/Appointment.php');

include('../main/databaseConnection.php');
$object = new Appointment;

if(!$object->is_Adminlogin()){
    header("Location: ../main/error.php");
}
?>



<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Doctor's Schedule</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/add_schedule_popup.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="add_schedule_button" >Add Doctor Schedule</button>

    <div id="add_schedule_popup" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="form-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Add Doctor Schedule</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form-body">
                <form method="POST" action="" id="doctor_schedule_form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action_type" id="action_type" value="add">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Doctor</label>
                    <select name="doctor_id" id="doctor_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Select Doctor</option>
                        <?php
                        $object->query = "SELECT * FROM doctor_info ";

                        $result = $object->get_result();

                        foreach($result as $row){
                            echo '
                            <option value="'.$row["doctor_id"].'">'.$row["doctor_firstname"].' '.$row["doctor_lastname"].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Schedule Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="schedule_date" id="schedule_date" required><br>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Timeslot</label>
                    <select name="schedule_timeslot" id="schedule_timeslot" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Select Timeslot</option>
                        <?php
                        $object->query = "SELECT * FROM timeslot";

                        $result = $object->get_result();

                        foreach($result as $row){
                            echo '
                            <option value="'.$row["schedule_timeslot"].'">'.$row["starting_time"].'-'.$row["ending_time"].' ('.$row["duration"].')</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
              
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Select Availability</label>
                    <select name="schedule_status" id="schedule_status" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="1">Available</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="form-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="close_button">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Confirm" name="submit_button">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var modal = document.getElementById("add_schedule_popup");
        var btn = document.getElementById("add_schedule_button");
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
        var close_button = document.getElementById("close_button");

        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeModal() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("doctor_schedule_form").reset();
        }
        span.onclick = closeModal;
        close_button.onclick = closeModal;
        
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("doctor_schedule_form").reset();
            }
        } 

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit_button").click(function(){
                e.preventDefault();
                var doctor_id = $("#doctor_id").val();
                var schedule_date = $("#schedule_date").val();
                var schedule_timeslot = $("#schedule_timeslot").val();
                var schedule_status = $("#schedule_status").val();
                var action_type = $("#action_type").val();
                console.log(doctor_id, schedule_date, schedule_timeslot, schedule_status, action_type);
                
                $.ajax({
                url: "modify_schedule_action.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {doctor_id:doctor_id,schedule_date:schedule_date,schedule_timeslot:schedule_timeslot,schedule_status:schedule_status,action_type:action_type},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    // Refresh the page or show a success message
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Success", data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php file that i am trying to send the values to

```
<?php
include('../class/Appointment.php');

$object = new Appointment;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  echo 'Received form data: ' . var_export($_POST, true);
}
if($_POST['action_type'] == 'add')
{
  $data = array(
    ':schedule_date'            =>  $_POST['schedule_date'],
    ':schedule_day'           =>    date('l', strtotime($_POST["schedule_date"])),
    ':schedule_status'    =>    $_POST['schedule_status'],
    ':schedule_timeslot'    =>  $_POST['schedule_timeslot'],
    ':doctor_id'                    =>  $_POST['doctor_id'],
    );

  $object->query = "INSERT INTO `schedule` (`schedule_date`, `schedule_day`, `schedule_status`, `schedule_timeslot`, `doctor_id`)
VALUES (:schedule_date,:schedule_day,:schedule_status,:schedule_timeslot,:doctor_id)";

  $object->execute($data);
  $output = 'Data added successfully';
}
```

until now, the php file does not react to anything i do inthe first file. can anyone help me troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have `e.preventDefault();` in your event handler but `e` is not defined.
This will cause an error preventing your ajax code from running and your form will submit normally to itself as its action is blank.

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(e){// define the event parameter
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: i have added the e but unfortunately nothing changes still